# Call an external command in Python

Tags: python, shell, command, subprocess, sox

How can I call an external command (as if I'd typed it at the Unix shell) from within a Python script?

I tried this code:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

and it works.
But when I try this code in a Python script:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['sox', '/home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav', '-n', 'stat', '2>&1', '|', 'sed', '-n', 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'])
```

it doesn't works. I get this error:

```
 sudo python getRMSAmplitude.py sox FAIL stat: Summary effect: unknown option
```

When I type this command in my Unix Shell:

```
sox ../../data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'
```

I get:

```
0.001754
```

What is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call([...], shell=True)
```

What's happening at the moment is that the rest of the arguments you're providing, `'2>&1', '|', 'sed', '-n', 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p']` are being interpreted by `sox` as arguments, because there isn't a shell to interpret the output redirection or the pipe. Tell `call` to use a shell, and it will be interpreted the same way as your command line.

Comment: Thank you,
Now I have no errors but when I run the script it gives no value back. The same with os.system("..."). Do I have to print it out or something?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but ok. No, `call` just runs the program, it doesn't return any output. You'll want `subprocess.check_output` to get whatever the process wrote to `stdout` or `stderr` into a variable.

Comment: Well I tried this: `output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-1'])
print 'Have %d bytes in output' % len(output)
print output` and I've got 99 bytes in output and the output, a list of files and dirs.

and then I tried this: `output = subprocess.check_output(["sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'"], shell=True)
print 'Have %d bytes in output' % len(output)
print output` and I've got this as output: `Have 2 bytes in output` but not the output itself.

Comment: For `call` and `check_output` and others, you either give a list containing individual elements, like `['ls', '-1']` or a string, `"ls -1"` - in your second example you have a list containing one long string. What happens when you just use the string, without it being a list?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with without it being a list?

Comment: `["sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'"]` is a list containing one string. Try `"sox /home/pi/OnoSW/data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'"`

Comment: I tried that but if I work with list or not I'm keep getting the same, it's like it gives the output but nothing is in it, here a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/h5CUOzs.png

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system("sox ../../data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'")
```

Answer (score 0):

another option (easier to use) is os.system('your original command')

```
import os
os.system("sox ../../data/opsoroassistant/rec.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^RMS     amplitude:[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'")
```

Answer (score -2):

The arguments in the call function should be in the same string as the command.

```
call('sed -arg1 -arg2 -argn')
```

Comment: Only if `shell=True` is set, otherwise it will think that `sed -arg1 -arg2 -argn` is one executable with spaces in the filename

Comment: [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)